# Given a low-rank symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and a basis of its nullspace, is there a fast way to get the nonzero eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

I have a (possibly dense) $k\times k$ real matrix $L = AA^T + B^T B$, a type of combinatorial Laplacian (self-adjoint, symmetric, positive semidefinite) of rank $(k-n)$ and possibly repeated nonzero eigenvalues. Suppose I have obtained a basis for the nullspace of $L$ through other means, which has $n$ vectors.

I want the least nonzero eigenvalues of $L$. Because $L$ is singular, many standard methods give a great deal of trouble for my computation.

For example, I have a $30,000\times 30,000$ matrix $L$ with rank $844$ (null space dimension $29156$). Computing the eigenvalues of this with the C++ package Eigen's SelfAdjointEigenSolver for eigenvalues only, which uses a symmetric QR algorithm. This computation takes $1.2$ hours on a reasonable processor (HPC node, not sure of exact specs, and definitely not memory-constrained). I have tried the Spectra C++ library, which uses an implicitly restarted Arnoldi/Lanczos method, but this tends to be unstable, even when using shift-and-invert tricks (shift by small nonzero number).

Meanwhile through the matlab web interface I can compute all eigenvalues of a random $30,000\times 30,000$ matrix in about $2$ seconds. It is sometimes unstable with my actual matrices. It seems matlab uses a Krylov-Schur algorithm or ARPACK.

I am guessing there is a way to eliminate the information I don't care about, maybe by constructing a $(k-n)\times (k-n)$ (so $844\times 844$) matrix $C$ such that $C$ has the same nonzero eigenvalues as $L$, and then I can compute the least eigenvalues of $C$ using methods that are more stable on nonsingular matrices. I am aware that $L$ being positive semidefinite implies $L=MM^T$ for possibly nonsquare $M$, and that $M^TM$ is a matrix with the same nonzero eigenvalues and may be smaller. Computing this decomposition would seem expensive to me and I don't know that it will solve the problem of being low-rank.

Is there an approach to my problem that would allow me to craft such a $(k-n)\times (k-n)$ matrix or otherwise estimate the least nonzero eigenvalue in a stable way?

Comment: I suppose you have tried writing L as a direct sum of L1+0 where L1 is an 844x844 matrix. The elements of L1 can be computed using the basis for the nullspace.